# Redox reaction involving a polyatomic ion

Tags: redox

Does it count as an autoredox reaction if two different elements from the same polyatomic ion or molecule change their oxidation numbers?
For example, for a reaction like this:

$$\ce{2KNO3(s) -> 2KNO2(s) + O2(g)}$$

Here, the nitrogen and oxygen in the nitrate ion undergo oxidation and reduction to from nitrite and diatomic oxygen, respectively. Does this count as a redox reaction since the same polyatomic ion undergoes both?

In my text book, it says that when an element in a molecule or polyatomic ion undergoes reduction or oxidation, we refer to the entire molecule or ion as being reduced or oxidized. I don’t know what effect this has on this reaction though.

Comment: Yes, this is a particular type of redox reactions known as disproportionation reactions.

Comment: Hi dahen! Please use [mathjax](https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/) to format questions and answers! Thanks.

Comment: @MollyCooL sorry about that, I'm on phone right now so it was kind of inconvenient to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any reaction in which one atom/ion loses some electrons and any other atom/ion gains those electrons is a redox reaction.

In your particular example, the oxygen atom is losing its electrons and the nitrogen atoms are gaining those electrons. So, it is definitely a redox reaction.

The reaction in which atoms from the same species are oxidised and reduced are called disproportionation reaction. So, the same reaction is also a disproportionation reaction.

Look at these examples too, 
[image: disproportionation reaction]

In both of these examples, the same molecule/ion/atom undergoes an oxidation as well as a reduction, so these are also disproportionation reaction.

Note that every disproportionation reaction is a redox reaction.

Comment: You should cite figures that you didn't personally make.